# discord.py Why my bot is online but I can't use any command or event

Tags: python, events, discord.py, command

**Im trying to let the command or event work. But it didn't succeed.
The terminal does not show any errors. There is my code from bot.py :**

```
from typing import Set
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">",owner_id=817014881349140481,intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(">>Bot is online<<")

with open("config.json",mode="r",encoding="utf8") as file:
    set = json.load(file)
    for Filename in os.listdir("./cmds"):
        if  Filename.endswith(".py"):
            bot.load_extension(f"cmds.{Filename[:-3]}")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        bot.run(set["token"])
```

**and this is from react.py :**

```
from tkinter import W
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from core.classes import Cog_Extension
import random
import json
import datetime
from discord.ui import View, Select, Button

with open("setting.json", "r",encoding="utf8") as jfile:
    jdata = json.load(jfile)


class React(Cog_Extension):
@commands.command()
@commands.has_any_role(971574272734683276)
async def sayd(self,ctx,title,*,msg):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed=discord.Embed(title=title,description=msg,                
    color=0x4bd4ec,timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_footer(text="By.Admins")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@commands.command()
@commands.has_any_role(971574272734683276)
async def clean(self,ctx,num:int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num+1)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=(f"Succees to clean {ctx.channel}'s {num} messages!"),
    color=0xa97bd4,timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_footer(text=(f"By . {ctx.author.name}"))
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(971586401957195808)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

@commands.command()
@commands.has_any_role(971574272734683276)
async def close(self,ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    await channel.delete()

@commands.slash_command(description="button test")
async def button(self,ctx):
    button = Button(label="Click to have the role!",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="✅")

    async def button_callback(interaction):
        user = interaction.user
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(971574207806832673)
        role = guild.get_role(971577551862509658)
        if role in user.roles:
            await interaction.response.send_message("**Now you dont't have the roles of visitor!**",ephemeral = True)
            await user.remove_roles(role)
        else:
            await user.add_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("**Now you have the roles of visitor!**",ephemeral = True)

    button.callback = button_callback

    view = View(timeout=False)
    view.add_item(button)
    await ctx.respond(content="**Click this**", view=view)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(React(bot))
```

**And I don't know why when I make a slash command it works but prefix command does not.
Can someone help me? thanks.**

**And if you guys need the pip list there is it**

**aiohttp            3.7.4.post0**
**async-timeout      3.0.1**
**attrs              21.4.0**
**cffi               1.15.0**
**chardet            4.0.0**
**discord-components 2.1.2**
**discord.py         2.0.0a4301+g081f483a**
**discord-ui         5.1.6**
**idna               3.3**
**multidict          6.0.2**
**pip                22.1.1**
**py-cord            2.0.0rc1**
**pycparser          2.21**
**PyNaCl             1.4.0**
**setuptools         58.1.0**
**six                1.16.0**
**typing_extensions  4.2.0**
**yarl               1.7.2**

Comment: There is "clash"  when combining `py-cord`, `discord.py`, and `discord-ui`. Try to make in 1 lib first like `discord.py`

Comment: Hey A63, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @MorpKnight now the problem is solved!